# How to assign y axes and scales to the layers in Dual-Axis multi-layer charts

Tags: vega-lite

I have a multi-layer visual showing actuals as a bar chart w. text marks aka labels, and a few different goals showing as line charts.

*Note: this is just a minimalistic test case. The real visual is more complex and looks differently.*

Is it possible to explicitly assign "y" axes and scales for each layer? I played with "resolve" statement and multi-level layers (groups of layers), but didn't find an acceptable solution.

The desired result: a bar chart is assigned to the Y axis on the left with its own scale, and both line charts (Target and North Star) are assigned to the Y axis on the right (same scale for both line charts, but different from the bar chart's scale).

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
        "values": [
          {"DATE": "2020-02-02", "Value": 50, "Target": 70, "North Star": 220},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-03", "Value": 70, "Target": 90, "North Star": 220},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-04", "Value": 80, "Target": 95, "North Star": 220},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-05", "Value": 85, "Target": 100, "North Star": 230},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-06", "Value": 91, "Target": 105, "North Star": 230}
        ]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "DATE", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "layer": [
        { "mark": "bar" },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": -7},
          "encoding": { "text": { "field": "Value", "type": "quantitative" }}
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line", "interpolate": "step"},
          "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "Target", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null },
            "color": { "value": "green"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line", "interpolate": "step"},
          "encoding": {"y": {"field": "North Star", "type": "quantitative" },
          "color": { "value": "red"}
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": { "scale": {"y": "independent"}}
  }
```

[Online Vega-Lite Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QEQ4cgV0Y1sljYwAbQ1GjwSABEAggBUAotcgAmAAwBIoHBvmpQAGpmFtbS-qpQ7ugATtTIeNYA7PFQAHLcySxgAMq6yda+AQC+6g4OTm5ePgFBIf4AzOGQUebIWTmQSanp1gCcA-mFiCVlFdW1dYYNHt44foH+ocEALF09MTgAHANDaRk4o9IJkJNFpSlz-jX2i8tNay2bbdJ70X1HV0SKTO1gAjP4JgU7rMcL52k8FoswG9VlBPlt-AA2X69Mag66nEY4cGAm5Q6b3cqw+FVF5GAC6dLAzzqkGQSng3E0jCU1GsBkWkAAHvzIAAzRjIMSaHyNbzXPAAT0I-ygSm4qB5ZkgLMFitFEqlMrW+z6CuVqsgAEdWOglHhmDpGFQdUzdUZIGJ0IrkFTbEyIMAoBhkgBrHzsB7MxH1APGEPh-SQJUqnx4ZBCjLXTT6nAiTLuwXsznc3n8qDpzPl8WS6U+U1dFOWm12h26B0u5m0pGFxxxiCQBOips+CRKM1QHnp5KEbhe9M+WDpwg6mOs4tcnl8-T94y55E1o0+QlZisWnwt+2OjsTyDoIWMKw4JSsMRiaO7gecsQFaumXFrNQyTIOyrpIhA3aLL2Sy7oOKSJgeI5rGOt5Tr6s7zpaS7ICu0Eehupbbge+5OIadZrLcFKzOaqZrJebZOp2eHGN+v76FA-4HFAwEypBPZxnxhj0mu3GWHOLrsZACBmKqTj7pAPKaDh7JKfaOqQVUQA)

[image: Chart]

Comment: Thanks David! 

Just to check my understanding, here is what should be done:
- wrap line marks into their own layer L2 (within the original layer statement L1)
- set any axis property for the LAST mark in that L2 layer to a non-empty value to instantiate an axis object for that mark and its siblings on L2
- set the resolve option for axis and scale in the outermost layer L1 to "independent". 

Is that all correct? Could you please elaborate on what exactly triggers the assignments in this use case?

Comment: My approach is isolate the marks of your two axes into two separate layers so they're contained. For the top level layer, state that the axes and scales are independent and for the layer containing the lines, the axes will automatically be shared (this is why you need to set an explicit title).  You also have a text mark which was generating an axis and confusing matters so I explicitly set that to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
   {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"DATE": "2020-02-02", "Value": 50, "Target": 70, "North Star": 220},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-03", "Value": 70, "Target": 90, "North Star": 220},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-04", "Value": 80, "Target": 95, "North Star": 220},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-05", "Value": 85, "Target": 100, "North Star": 230},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-06", "Value": 91, "Target": 105, "North Star": 230}
        ]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "DATE", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "layer": [
        {"mark": "bar"},
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": -7},
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null}
          }
        },
        {
          "layer": [
            {
              "mark": {"type": "line", "interpolate": "step"},
              "encoding": {
                "y": {"field": "Target", "type": "quantitative"},
                "color": {"value": "green"}
              }
            },
            {
              "mark": {"type": "line", "interpolate": "step"},
              "encoding": {
                "y": {
                  "field": "North Star",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "axis": {"title": "Shared Line"}
                },
                "color": {"value": "red"}
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"axis": {"y": "independent"}, "scale": {"y": "independent"}}
    }
```